# I figured out the answer to a question I set a bounty for. Should I post the answer, or give it some time for other people to answer?

Tags: discussion, bounty, self-answer

I asked a question, got no response, placed a bounty of +100 and then while I was away I figured it out. When I came back to my computer, there was an answer, but it's not quite correct and as it stands I wouldn't consider it bounty-worthy. My question is, what would be the most "conscientious" way to proceed in this situation? Should I just post the answer, or should I allow other people the chance to post an answer so that I can reward it? I'm not going to get any of that rep back, so I might as well just give it away to someone who can use it. My only concern is that if I post a correct answer, then nobody will want to post anything, the question having already been resolved. Consequently no one will get a bounty. What does the community think?

Comment: I think that it is easy to place a lot of importance on reputation, but it's important to remember that these are ultimately just some internet points. Go ahead and answer your question --- give the best answer you can.

Comment: You needn't worry about no one getting the bounty. Even if you don't award it, half of it goes to the answer with the most post-offer upvotes (or something like that – the exact rules can be found onsite, if you look hard enough for them).

Comment: @GerryMyerson It can be found [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/bounty): "If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount (or the full amount, if the answer is also accepted)...." And also some other links with information relevant to bounties are collected [in the tag-info](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/bounty/info)

Comment: By the way, that answer that's "not quite correct" – I trust you have left a comment on it, explaining the manner in which it is deficient.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I did. But I decided that the answer was not so bad as it seemed before, and so I changed my mind about awarding the bounty.